# Create PFQuery for PFRelation with zero objects

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery, pfrelation

I want to create a PFQuery for a PFRelation to find objects where the specified relation has zero objects in it. Here's what I've tried:

```
PFQuery *categoryQuery = [CatalogCategory query];
[categoryQuery whereKeyDoesNotExist:@"subcategories"];
```

But I get an error saying I can't use this operator on a PFRelation key. How else could I achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: From what I understand you would use a PFRelation query after getting the objects first, just like you can't save a relation to an object that hasn't been saved first. Something like `PFRelation *relation = [yourObjectInstanceHere relationforKey:@"subcategories"]`

Comment: Yeah but I don't have an objectInstance to start with. I'm searching for objects that don't have any subcategories, so my starting point is "all objects". I don't know if that makes sense or not.

Comment: Exactly, so you find all the objects first (without parameters) or not, then do a PFRelation query : see here: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#relations-using-parse-relations second topic

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `[categoryQuery whereKey:@"subcategories" equalTo:nil]`?

It may be that the `whereKeyDoesNotExist:` method is unavailable for objects of the `PFRelation` type.

Comment: Well, whereKey:equalTo: must have a non-nil object passed to it. So, that won't work. It does seem like the obvious solution though, doesn't it.